# Why won't my custom function execute from the file editor in Python?

Tags: python, function, return

I recently started a Python course on Udemy. I couldn't get a grasp on the *return* function.

For example, in the following simple program:

```
def f(a, b):
    x = a + b
    return x

f(3, 3)
```

Simply executing this as a .py will not display the result **6**

However, manually executing `f(3, 3)` in the console *will* display **6**

Could I get some intuition or explanation as to what is happening here?

I'm running Python 3.8.3 on Windows 10

Comment: `print(f(3, 3))`

Comment: Executing commands in the console will display the output from the last command executed, in this case, the value from `f(3, 3)`. This does not happen when you run the .py file, so you need an explicit print statement.

Comment: @MartinNečas indeed I understand that syntax, but I was just wondering why doing the same thing i.e. executing `f(3, 3)` in console and in the script gives different results

Comment: @DavidBuck that does make sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've defined the function in the script, but have not called it anywhere.

You need to call it and store the result in a variable.

Your script should be like this:

```
def f(a, b):
    x = a + b
    return x

result = f(3,3)
print(result)
```

Finally you will run `python a.py`

Comment: in line 5, where I have written `f(3, 3)` , is that not considered _'calling the function'_?

Comment: Yes, you have called the function. But in order to print it, you need an explicit `print` statement.